# How to place the Divs underneath each other without big space

Tags: html

How to place  the divs underneath each other without big space using Bootstrap

Html Code :

```
<div class=""row>
<div class="col-md-6">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>

</div>



<div class="col-md-6">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>

</div>


<div class="col-md-6">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>

</div>


</div>
```

The following image , will explain the problem i face 
[image]

I don't need that space inside the circle  , what could i do to make the divs underneath each other without space ? 
Thank you

Comment: Your HTML structure won't allow you to do it. you need to reconsider it.

Comment: There is no style ! i am using bootstrap grid

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange div in this way in bootstrap inorder to meet your requirement.

```
<div class=""row>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <li>Item</li>
               <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Comment: this way will not work with me , because the content is dynamic .. is there another way ?